# How to use dropdownlistfor in mvc3 razor with model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to use below property in my view with dropdownbox.
How could I ? 
I have tried so many ways but
Please help

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Topic
{
    get
    {
        return  new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Science", Selected=true },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "History" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Physics" },
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added your view code.

Basically you need to add a `@model`  to  your view like this:

```
@model MySampleApplication.Models.ModelName
```

And then in your view you should be accessing like this :

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m=>m.Topic, Model.Topic)
```

[DropDownListFor with ASP.NET MVC](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) from Scott Allen

Hope it helps

---

**EDIT**

Say you have your model class like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Topic
{
    get
    {
        return  new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Science", Selected=true },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "History" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Physics" },
        };
    }
}
}
```

Try like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
   MyModel model=new MyModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Please show your controller code. Have you instantiated your model class and passed that object to your view ?

Comment: i have'nt. my controller is just like 
public ActionResult Index()
{
retuer View()
}

But my model is having data in Get.
I think it should work ..

confused please help.

Comment: I could see the data. Even i've tried in a sample application and it works perfect. Try debugging and check whether you have your Topic property filled with dropdown values in the model object

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

**Model**

```
public SelectList Topic
            {
                get
                {
                    return new SelectList(
                      new List<SelectListItem> {
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Science", Selected = true },
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "History" },
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Physics" }
                    },"Value","Text"
                    );
                }
            }


public int selectedType {get;set;}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedType , Model.Topic)
```

Comment: thanx for reply dear but its giving the same error
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you show the controller code? are you passing model to view as return view(model)??

Comment: no I am not passing anything . Actually its a Create Action of my controller. 
I just want to bind predefined data in dropdown.

Comment: You should give more details like your view markup and controller code, if you want us to help you.

Comment: Actually I just want to use below mentioned model this in Dropdownlist
I am having get property here so no need to get data from controller

public SelectList Topic
        {
            get
            {
                return new SelectList(
                  new List<SelectListItem> {
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Science", Selected = true },
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "History" },
                      new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Physics" }
                    }
                );
            }
        }